# Xamarin Forms - iOS style picker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to create an iOS style picker in Xamarin Forms that will be displayed on Android and iOS devices.

Here is a screenshot of the picker I need:
[iOS style picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqecb.png)

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms has a built in [Picker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/) control.  It will render as an iOS style Picker on iOS, and as a native Android picker on Android.

Comment: Jason thanks but I am looking for an IOS style picker implementation for Android.

Comment: if you want an Android control that looks like an iOS control, you will need to write one, or find a third party control.  Forms is designed to use the underlying native control for each platform, so that the user has a native experience for the platform that they're using